# How to change attribute value to preceding-sibling value

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I have a specific requirement where I need to change the attribute value of current element with preceding sibling node value.

**Current XML**

```
<com:row>
<com:new>
    <com:Component ExcludeInd="false">
        <com:CatTypeCode>35</com:CatTypeCode>
        <com:SubCatTypeCode>055508</com:SubCatTypeCode>
        <com:ComCode>1000</com:ComCode>
        <com:VComponentCode>nbr</com:VComponentCode>
        <com:Val Value="sometext">250</com:Val>
    </com:Component>
</com:new>
</com:row>
```

**XSLT**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:com="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="../com:Component/com:Val">
          <xsl:element name="com:Val" namespace="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
          <xsl:variable name="myVar" select="preceding-sibling::com:VComponentCode"/>
            <xsl:attribute name="ValueType"><xsl:value-of select="$myVar"/></xsl:attribute>     
             <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
          </xsl:element>
       </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Expected XML**

```
<com:row>
<com:new>
    <com:Component ExcludeInd="false">
        <com:CatTypeCode>35</com:CatTypeCode>
        <com:SubCatTypeCode>055508</com:SubCatTypeCode>
        <com:ComCode>1000</com:ComCode>
        <com:VComponentCode>nbr</com:VComponentCode>
        <com:Val Value="nbr">250</com:Val>
    </com:Component>
</com:new>
</com:row>
```

I am able to change the value in attribute when I hardcode the value, but not as a variable.

Comment: Your XML is not well-formed as posted, some tags don't have corresponding closing tag : `com:SubCateTypeCode` vs `com:SubCatTypeCode`, `com:ComCode` vs `com:ComponentCode`. Please fix that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you have a *well-formed* XML input, you can try the following XSL Transformation :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:com="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="com:Val/@Value">
    <xsl:attribute name="Value">
      <xsl:value-of select="parent::com:Val/preceding-sibling::com:VComponentCode"/>
    </xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**brief explanation :**

- `<xsl:template match="@* | node()">` : Identity template. This template copies matched elements and attributes to output XML as it is in the source XML.
- `<xsl:template match="com:Val/@Value">` : Overrides identity template for `Value` attribute of `com:Val` element. Instead of copy the attribute to output this template creates new `Value` attribute with value taken from preceding sibling `com:VComponentCode` element.